# nginx with symfony2 in subdirectory AND normal projects

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, nginx

I have a problem with my nginx configuration.

On most of pages and google search entries i found things like "nginx and symfony2" or "nginx and symfony2 in subdirectory".
But i not find some thing about this configuration:

1. Normal php file projects (path like localhost/project -> /srv/www/project/index.php / ruled per index)
2. Symfony2 projects (path like localhost/symfony2 -> /srv/www/symfony2/web/app.php (default) and manually app_dev.php / unknown!?)

#### Current configuration

```
server
{
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /srv/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm app.php app_dev.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php @rewriteapp /index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location ~ ^\/symfony2
    {
        #rewrite ^\/symfony2(.*)$ /symfony2/web$1 last;
        #root /srv/www/symfony2/web;
        alias /srv/www/symfony2/web;
    }

    location @rewriteapp
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$)
    {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thank's in advance for each tip!

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should help.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /srv/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm app.php app_dev.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php /index.php;
        location ~ .*\.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /symfony2 {
        alias /srv/www/symfony2/web;

        location ~ .*\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /symfony2(?<path>.*)$ {
            root /srv/www/symfony2/web; 
            try_files $path $path/ /app.php$path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `2013/12/06 14:30:24 [error] 5755#0: *189 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /symfony2/web/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"`
`::1 - - [06/Dec/2013:14:30:24 +0100] "GET /symfony2/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 47 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [06/Dec/2013:14:30:34 +0100] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"`

Comment: I changed it a little (/symphony2/app.php replaced with regex), please try it now

Comment: **Works:** `http://localhost/symfony2/app_dev.php/en/test/index`
**Works:** `http://localhost/symfony2/app.php/en/test/index`
**DOESNT works:** `http://localhost/symfony2/en/test/index`
**Works:** `http://localhost`
**Works:** `http://localhost/index.php`

Comment: DOESNT works: http://localhost/symfony2/en/test/index - should it work? if so what script should handle it?

Comment: Thats the only thing which is wrong. Projects should completely rewrited to web directory: **localhost/symfony2/en/test/index == /srv/www/symfony2/app.php/en/test/index**

Every thing is perfect. I can use normal projects and symfony2 projects ^^ But the "index" / default file is empty... It should be the app.php file :)

Thank you!!!

Comment: it was localhost/symfony2/en/test/index == /srv/www/symfony2/app.php/symfony2/en/test/index before, fixed.

Comment: No... Bader than before! Now the "web" directory is ignored. Each asset is rewrited to symfony2 directory... not to the symfony2/web directory. (( sorry, at the example one comment above, i said it wrong... Mean: **localhost/symfony2/en/test/index == /srv/www/symfony2/web/app.php/en/test/index** ))

The app.php and app_dev.php link doesnt work now :/

Comment: If you open "localhost/symfony2" then the **default** should be /symfony2/web/app.php. But if you open "localhost/symfony2/app_dev.php" the location should be "/symfony2/web/app_dev.php". Do you understand? :)